# magento 2.4.4.p2 cms page save Custom layout update is invalid

Tags: layout, cms-pages, magento2.4.4, custom-layout-update

I am trying to save the existing cms page getting **Custom layout update is invalid** after upgrading[image] 2.3 to 2.4.4 p2 getting this error.
if I save a new page saving properly works fine

I have checked the below function
**public function isValid($value, $schema = self::LAYOUT_SCHEMA_PAGE_HANDLE, $isSecurityCheck = true)**
placed logs in log getting
**NULL**

Comment: as far as i know, Custom layout update in Content > Pages  is deprecated in Magento 2.4 versions.

Comment: @nhungoduc but in my Magento admin panel existing cms pages getting this issue

Comment: try {
            $page = $this->pageRepository->getById($this->getPageId());
            if ($page->getCustomLayoutUpdateXml() || $page->getLayoutUpdateXml()) {
                $options[] = ['label' => 'Use existing layout update XML', 'value' => '_existing_'];
            }
            foreach ($this->customLayoutManager->fetchAvailableFiles($page) as $layoutFile) {
                $options[] = ['label' => $layoutFile, 'value' => $layoutFile];
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }